# Python h2o.init() cannot find Java

Tags: python, h2o

I'm following the instructions [here](http://learn.h2o.ai/content/hands-on_training/python_with_h2o.html) to setup Python to use H2O.

Despite installing Java in the default location (C:\Program Files\Java), `h2o.init()` is unable to find Java and exits with ValueError:

```
Cannot find Java. Please install the latest JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

java.exe is clearly in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin.

I can't figure out why `h2o.init()` is failing. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried on a different computer, and I get the same results.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu users, try running this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Answer (score 3):

I find it easiest to use [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/). Install H2O and Java Development Kit (JDK) with conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge h2o-py openjdk -y
```

For me, H2O automatically found this Java version correctly even in my separate conda environment I created for H2O.

Comment: Similar approach: I installed openjdk and the H2O Python module from [H2O docs](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#install-in-python) `pip install -f http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_Py.html h2o`

Comment: Isn't that only installing H2O? So you installed java separately?

Comment: Yes, but I said I installed openjdk **and** H2O Python module from H2O docs - as opposed to h2o-py.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to set JAVA_HOME environment variable manually and that might work.Following is the process.

> Set JAVA_HOME:

```
Right click My Computer and select Properties.

On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
```

Then go to the h2o directory and run

```
java -jar h2o.jar
```

However if still it can't find java then run following command

at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51

```
java -jar \path to\h2o.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I changed the JAVA_HOME environmental variable and also tried setting in the PATH, and I'm still getting an error. However, a clue: When I go to C:\Anaconda\h2o_jar and click on h2o.jar and then run h2o.init() from within python, I see the report that the cluster is healthy. I tried reconfiguring my JAVA_HOME and PATH to C:\Anaconda\h2o_jar, but that didn't work. Can I direct h2o.init() to run this file in any way?

Comment: Did you try this command in MS-DOS while being inside java directory of h2o 
java -jar h2o.jar 
and then ran h2o.init() in R?

Answer (score 1):

We need to install both h2o and h2o-py. After install h2o, we'll get h2o.jar inside "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\h2o_jar", which is the folder that h2o.init() looks at for h2o.jar.